# Sending list pointer to function

Tags: c, function, pointers

For an exercise I'm doing about pointers in C, I want insert a struct at the start of a linked list by sending the pointer `listStart` to the `insertEntry` function along with the struct that I want to insert. However, with this current code I'm unable to do this because the `listStart` pointer doesn't carry along with it the address of what it was pointing to in the main function (the very 1st struct of the list).

I understand that I'm only copying the pointer itself into the `insertEntry` function and therefore the address that it was pointing to is left out. That means all I'm getting of the `listStart` pointer in the `insertEntry` function is a null pointer.

To solve this problem I've tried to send the `listStart` to the `insertEntry` function as a pointer, however, that just gave me a pointer to pointer which points to null. I tried to send the address of `listStart` to the function which didn't work because it was sending null to the function.

Is it possible to do this and I'm just missing out on something? Or is this not possible?

```
// header to include standard input and output
#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};

    
// prototype for insertEntry function
void insertEntry(struct entry *l, struct entry *i, struct entry *j);

int main(void)
{
    
    // declaration of array for linked list
    struct entry list1 = { 1 }, list2 = { 2 }, list3 = { 3 }, list4 = { 4 }, list5 = { 5 }, insert = { 8 }; 
    struct entry *listStart = &list1;
    
    // test to see if the value of the insert.value struct is correct
    printf("insert.value = %i\n", insert.value);
    
    
    // assign pointers in list.next to the next struct in the list to create a linked list
    list1.next = &list2;
    list2.next = &list3;
    list3.next = &list4;
    list4.next = &list5;
    list5.next = (struct entry *) 0;
    
    // print the linked list to make sure the pointers are going to the correct struct member
    printf("Original list!\n");
    while ( listStart != (struct entry *) 0 ) 
    {
        printf ("%i\n", listStart->value);
        listStart = listStart->next;
    }
    
    // send struct to change and struct to insert
    insertEntry(listStart, &insert, &list1);
    
    // restart the list from the beginning because in the last while loop the listStart was assigned to the null pointer.
    listStart  = &list1;
    
    // print the new list to show what has been inserted and moved around
    printf("New list!\n");
    while ( listStart != (struct entry *) 0 ) 
    {
        printf ("%i\n", listStart->value);
        listStart = listStart->next;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

// function to insert a new struct in the list and redirect an old struct in the list
void insertEntry(struct entry *l, struct entry *i, struct entry *j)
{
    i->next = l; // this is assigning the mem add of the pointer is list2.next to that of insert.next
    l = i; // this is assigning the mem add of i which would be insert.value to the pointer in list2.next
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**

You are changing where `listStart` points to in the first `while` loop. At the end of that loop, the value of `listStart` is `NULL`.

I suggest you use a different variable to iterate over the items of the list and keep `listStart` pointing to the start of the list.

```
struct entry *iter = listStart;
while ( iter != NULL ) 
{
    printf ("%i\n", iter->value);
    iter = iter->next;
}
```

Use `iter` in both loops to keep `listStart` pointing to the start of the list.

**Problem 2**

After the call to `insertEntry`, `listStart` does not point to the start of the list. Neither is `list1` the first entry in the list. `insert` is the object at the start of the list. Replace the line

```
listStart  = &list1;
```

by

```
listStart  = &insert;
```

**Suggestion for cleanup**

The line

```
l = i;
```

in `insertEntry` is useless. It does not do anything in the function. It does not change anything in `main` either. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of how you would do your task:

```
void insertEntry(struct entry** pplistStart, struct entry *pNewEntry)
{
     pNewEntry->next = *pplistStart;
     *pplistStart = pNewEntry;
}
```

It can be called like

```
 insertEntry(&listStart, insert);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two issue :-

One is :-

```
printf("Original list!\n");
while ( listStart->next != (struct entry *) 0 )
{
    printf ("%i\n", listStart->value);
    listStart = listStart->next;
}

// send struct to change and struct to insert
insertEntry(listStart, &insert, &list1);
```

in insertEntry() listStart now point to NULL, so when you call insertEntry() you will get segfault.

Second Problem is :-

Your logic to passed address of l in i->next is wrong. you should assign address of i in l->next.

```
void insertEntry(struct entry *l, struct entry *i, struct entry *j)
{
    i->next = l; // this is assigning the mem add of the pointer is list2.next to that of insert.next
    l = i; // this is assigning the mem add of i which would be insert.value to the pointer in list2.next

}
```

I Modified your program Have a look.

```
// header to include standard input and output
#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};


// prototype for insertEntry function
void insertEntry(struct entry *l, struct entry *i, struct entry *j);

int main(void)
{

    // declaration of array for linked list
    struct entry list1 = { 1 }, list2 = { 2 }, list3 = { 3 }, list4 = { 4 }, list5 = { 5 }, insert = { 8 };
    struct entry *listStart = &list1;

    // test to see if the value of the insert.value struct is correct
    printf("insert.value = %i\n", insert.value);

    // assign pointers in list.next to the next struct in the list to create a linked list
    list1.next = &list2;
    list2.next = &list3;
    list3.next = &list4;
    list4.next = &list5;
    list5.next = (struct entry *) 0;

    // print the linked list to make sure the pointers are going to the correct struct member
    printf("Original list!\n");
    while ( listStart->next != (struct entry *) 0 )
    {
        printf ("%i\n", listStart->value);
        listStart = listStart->next;
    }

    // send struct to change and struct to insert
    insertEntry(listStart, &insert, &list1);

    // restart the list from the beginning because in the last while loop the listStart was assigned to the null pointer.
    listStart  = &list1;

    // print the new list to show what has been inserted and moved around
    printf("New list!\n");
    while ( listStart != (struct entry *) 0 )
    {
        printf ("%i\n", listStart->value);
        listStart = listStart->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

// function to insert a new struct in the list and redirect an old struct in the list
void insertEntry(struct entry *l, struct entry *i, struct entry *j)
{
    l->next = i; // this is assigning the mem add of the pointer is list2.next to that of insert.next
    l = i; // this is assigning the mem add of i which would be insert.value to the pointer in list2.next

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `while ( listStart != (struct entry *) 0 )` loop execution, `listStart` is pointing to `NULL` and inside `insertEntry`, you are assigning insert's `next` pointer to l`istStart` which is `NULL`.

You can try following two solutions,

1. Inside `insertEntry` change

`i->next = l`

To

`i->next = j`

or

2. Before calling `insertEntry` point `listStart` pointer to `list1`

`listStart = &list1;
insertEntry(listStart, &insert, &list1);`